# How to find words in NSString when app is localized?

Tags: ios, ios6, localization, internationalization, nsstring

This question is related to localization or internationalization. I have a string containing a bunch of words. Ex Firstname Middlename Lastname
I want to find the count of words in this sentence. Generally I use 
[string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]. This works in english because the word separator is space. But in other languages it might vary. So how to get the localized components of a string.

Comment: what character could be other than white space? in other languages?

Comment: @nsgulliver Yes, he mentioned internationalization. So, Japanese for example.

Comment: @pearlwhite If you are talking specifically about splitting names, you have bigger problems than whitespaces. A 3 character name in Japanese does not necessarily represent first, middle and last names.

Comment: We are handling firstname lastname issue by using ABPersonCompositeNameFormat.

Comment: Are words in Chinese separated by whitespace?  发自我的 iPhone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With iOS5 Apple introduced in the Foundation framework some linguistic capability. In particular there is the

```
NSLinguisticTagger
```

class that analyses natural-language
 text and tags it. One of these tags is the "word". The usage of this class is a bit complex (it is asynchronous and block based) but it is also powerful. There is an excellent WWDC video that covers the subject.

Comment: Excellent. Link to the above mentioned video https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=128 in case anyone wants.